# How can I support joists which intersect at more than 45 degrees?

Tags: deck, joists

I am building a deck in the shape of a donut octagon and have some joists meet at odd angles (67.5 deg / 112.5 deg).

I have found adjustable joist hangers (ex [Simpson Strong Tie LSSJ](https://www.strongtie.com/facemounthangersssl_solidsawnlumberconnector/lssj_hanger/p/lssj) ) but they only adjust to 45 deg.

Is there joist hangers that will work for such hangers? Is there a different mechanism for working at these angles?

Answer (score 1):

My first step would be to call Simpson and ask them if they have (or know of) a product that you could use in this application.

If Simpson is unable to come up with a solution, I'd suggest using a ledger strip for vertical support of your floor joists. A ledger strip is a 2x2 or 2x4 nailed to the deck band underneath the floor joist ends.

For example, lets say you are using 2x10's for your band and 2x8's for your floor joists. Once you have the band complete and the floor joist locations laid out, you toenail the floor joists in. Once you have the joists in place, you run a 2x2 ledger strip underneath the ends of the joists, using the nailing schedule required by your building code.

The strip is installed second to make sure the tops of the joists are even with the band and the strip is tight against the bottom of the joist. Slight variations in the dimensions of the joists might make for an uneven decking surface if the strip is installed first.

I attached an illustration. Please note that the diagram shows the joist notched. This is not required if using a band that is larger than the joists.[image]